# InvalidAsynchronousStateException in Framework code - do I need to care?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, winforms

I have a WPF app which hosts a couple of WinForms controls.

Occasionally, I get on the `.NET SystemEvents` thread some first chance `InvalidAsynchronousStateException`s which are always caught by the Framework code (so I only see them in the Output window in Visual Studio).

> **System.ComponentModel.InvalidAsynchronousStateException**: 'An error occurred invoking the method.  The destination thread no longer exists.'

The stack trace looks like:

```
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback, object)
    System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SystemEventInvokeInfo.Invoke(bool, object[])    
    System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.RaiseEvent(bool, object, object[])
    System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.OnUserPreferenceChanging(int, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)
    System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowProc(System.IntPtr, int, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)
    [Native to Managed Transition]
    [Managed to Native Transition]
    System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowThreadProc()
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object, bool)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object, bool)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, object)
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The exceptions are always raised while the app is up and running, not at startup - so the main UI thread is definitely available.

Do I need to care? Is this a .NET Framework bug/feature or is it my app's bug/misconfiguration?
It's hard for me to understand if there's something wrong. I don't see any direct impact on my app (no deadlocks, no crashes, no GUI glitches), but who knows.

Windows 10, .NET Framework 4.7.

Comment: I would care...but that is just me. If time was not an issue, I would try to trace around your code and see where it is.

Comment: @DavidBentley, this is not in my code. This is in Framework code.

Comment: Even though the exception is thrown in the Framework, it is possible whatever is using the Framework is causing it. It might be benign and something for the Framework devs to look at, but a good example of something similar is calling `Window.Close` before calling `Window.Show`. You get a "hidden" exception in the Presentation Framework but it is essentially caused by the developer.

Comment: @DavidBentley, not in this case. If you take a look on the stack trace, you will notice that the whole sequence runs on the .NET system event thread and is triggered by an operating system event. The `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` is also managed by WinForms and does not depend on developer's code.

Comment: Ahhh yes. I am guessing then it must be using Winforms controls in WPF. What controls are you using? I have only ever used the System Tray control from WinForms in WPF and have never seen this error.